# How to reset BIOS on ASUS K53E

Tags: laptop, bios, passwords

My BIOS is password-protected, so that I can't access the BIOS settings (I don't have problems with booting into Windows XP). The BIOS is made by American Megatrends (AMI). I've been trying some utilities to reset the BIOS from Windows, but I don't think that's possible (I don't want to mess up my computer and I find Command Prompt to be quite difficult to use). I've attempted to reset the CMOS through a hardware method, but I can't find a switch/plug/button to do so. The only place I haven't checked is under the RAM, because they're held quite firmly and I don't want to brake anything, since I'm not used to working with hardware componenets. So, is there any way for me to reset the BIOS?

Answer (score 2):

As few people have already mentioned you would need to use the `BIOS reset jumper` (if one exists) or remove `CMOS` battery for about 10 minutes. The battery on `ASUS K53E` is located on the other side of motheroard - under the keyboard. You would need to carefully remove keyboard (mind the zif connecters - they are easy to damage). Then you would need to remove the metal plate sitting under the keyboard, this will also involve removing touchpad and all front panel plastics. This will reveal the motherboard and `CMOS battery`. See the picture below:

[image]

Do not attempt to do this yourself if you are not qualified for the job - take the laptop to the repair specialist.

Links:

- [source 1](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Asus+K53E-MT1+Motherboard+Replacement/10166)
- [source 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20140610203153/http://gentechpcforums.com/Images/Manuals/K53%20Series%20Guide%20Chapter%2002-v1.0.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

CMOS is usual static RAM supplied by lithium coin cell. So just find and remove that battery, wait for a few seconds, and return it to its place.